# selected elements in a drop down list don't appear in database after submitting form in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, model-view-controller, drop-down-menu, web

I'm new to cakephp and have some problems with drop down list in the form.
I have a table named Estates that has a direction field. the values of direction field are in a set consist of "southern" and "northern".
but every time by submitting the form the value of this field in new record of table is southern and doesn't change.
the code of drop down menu is here:

```
<?php
    $options=array('southern','northern');
    echo $this->Form->select('direction',$options);?>
```

the code of controller is:

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    $a=$this->request->data['Estate']['username'];
    $d=$this->Estate->findbyusername($a);
    $x=count($d);
    if($x>0){
        $this->Estate->create();}}
if ($this->Estate->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The estate has been saved'));}
```

"findbyusername" query is in Estate model and validate the username who submits the form.

Comment: add also code of controller

Comment: what is all that find stuff above your save call? it has nothing to do there and is most likely the source of the issue. remove all that and leverage the model for this - as it should be done.

Comment: well..explain more.because i'm not good in english:-(